# Can't get awesome widgets (volume) to work

Tags: lua, awesome-wm, manjaro

I recently started using awesomewm and im loving it, except im having trobule with widgets. Whenever i try to put them in my rc.lua awesome breaks. I am really bad at lua. I just want a working volume widget. Anyone can specify where do i put the widget inside the rc.lua?
[This is the github repo which i cloned in ~/.config/awesome](https://github.com/streetturtle/awesome-wm-widgets)
Thanks.

Comment: Please share any relevant code in the Question, as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Not all users will click on links and therefore won't be able to help reproduce, and solve, your issue.

Comment: On top of what @tjheslin1 said, please also include the error message and the relevant lines of your `rc.lua`. One easy way to test changes to your config without risking terminating your session is to use `Xephyr :2 -screen 1280x720` and then `DISPLAY=:2 awesome` from another terminal. You will get the error text in your terminal.

Comment: You need to add the `require` line at the top, then search for `s.mytasklist` to add the `volume_widget()` line